# Which is correct? “It is me/I who am your teacher”

Tags: pronouns, subject-vs-object-pronouns

Can you help me with this?

Are both sentences correct?

> It is me who am your teacher

Or

> It is I who am your teacher

Comment: Ask yourself: do I say `I am` or `me am`?. `It is I who am your teacher`, but this is very old fashioned. `It is me who is your teacher` is more likely.

Comment: We actually would say: I am your teacher.

Comment: It is I who am your teacher, not that bozo over there/your uncle/the guy at the store.

Answer (score 1):

Only the latter is correct. It "follows the general rules for relative clauses, with the relative pronoun *who* being construed as 1st person singular by virtue of its anaphoric relation to *I*" (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002: p. 507).

If you want to use *is*, the pronoun has to be accusative. This is the case of *3rd person override in cleft relatives* (ibid.). And as Michael Harvey mentioned in the comment, this is more common in Present-Day English:

> It is **me** who is your teacher

Comment: Do we really help learners by talking about anaphoric relations and ibids?

Comment: @Ronald Sole Why is it a problem for one to be specific when citing? A learner could refer to this page if they want to and that helps provide better understanding and strengthens my answer.

Comment: If we follow the entirety of the Michael Harvey comment under the question, the final sentence is strange. To paraphrase the comment, "Ask yourself: Do you say `I is` or `me is`? Well, I would say neither. But if we use a different pronoun, it would be `he is` (the subjective case) ***not*** `him is` (the objective case). Despite both of those tests, `it is me who is` (the objective case) is being used here. I actually suspect this is like the answer to *Who is at the door?* Strictly speaking, it should be *It is* ***I***, but pragmatically, in modern English, it's *It is* ***me***.